# filter on value set intersection within a group

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Group  |  Source  |  Name
___________________________
  A    |    X     |  Jolly
  A    |    X     |  Stone
  A    |    X     |  Jolly
  A    |    Y     |  Sand
  B    |    X     |  Sand
  B    |    X     |  Stone
  B    |    Y     |  Stone
  C    |    X     |  Sand
  C    |    X     |  Stone
```

I want to find all `Group`s where each group of `Source`s share no common `Name`s. Essentially in the example above, I want `Group` `A` as all groupings of `Source` (`X` and `Y`) `Name`s share no common values. For this example we can assume there will only be 2 `Source`s (`X` and `Y`) and not all `Group`s have more than 1 `Source`. I am only interested in `Group`s with both `Source`s `X` and `Y` and no `Name` intersection.

The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
Group  |  Source  |  Name
___________________________
  A    |    X     |  Jolly
  A    |    X     |  Stone
  A    |    X     |  Jolly
  A    |    Y     |  Sand
```

I have tried, doing a `grouby` on `Group` then supplied a function to the chained `filter` method like so:

```
def find_no_intersection(df):
    return (
        len(df[df.Source == 'X'].Name.values) > 0 and 
        len(df[df.Source == 'Y'].Name.values) > 0 and 
        (
            len(
                set(df[df.Source == 'X'].Name.values) & 
                set(df[df.Source == 'Y'].Name.values)
            ) == 0
        )
    )

df.groupby(['Group']).filter(find_no_intersection)
```

Is this the right way? Is there a better way?

Comment: share your expected outcome.

Comment: @adhg that group in the example DF would be what I would like to find

Comment: @adhg I extended the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `nunique()`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Group')['Name'].transform(lambda x: x.size == x.nunique())]
```

Output:

```
  Group Source   Name
0     A      X  Jolly
1     A      X  Stone
2     A      Y   Sand
```

Update to answer:

```
(df.loc[
    df['Group'].map(
        df.groupby(['Group','Source'])['Name']
        .agg(set)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(lambda x: len(set.intersection(*x))==0))
        ])
```

or:

```
m1 = df['Group'].map(df.groupby(['Group','Name'])['Source'].nunique().eq(1).groupby(level=0).all())
m2 = df.groupby('Group')['Source'].transform('nunique').eq(df['Source'].nunique())

df.loc[m1 & m2]
```

Output:

```
  Group Source   Name
0     A      X  Jolly
1     A      X  Stone
2     A      X  Jolly
3     A      Y   Sand
```

Comment: I have updated my example, and clarified the goal, your method would return no rows for that updated example while `Group` `A` would meet the conditions of the updated query.

Comment: I made an update that should answer the question

Comment: That was way faster than the groupby/filter method I was using!

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you can help with my newest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993978/count-commonalities-frequency-among-subgroups

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do that with the following.

```
df[~df['Group'].isin(df[df[['Source','Name']].duplicated()]['Group'])]
```

Comment: I have updated my example to clarify further. Your method worked for my incomplete example but would filter out my target records if one `Group`'s `Source` had duplicate `Name`s