# Count commonalities/frequency among subgroups

Tags: python, pandas, split-apply-combine

I have a Series as follows:

```
(multi-index)              |  Count  |
Group  |  Source  |  Name  |
______________________________________
  A    |    X     |  Jolly |   2
       |          |  Stone |   1
       |    Y     |  Sand  |   1
  B    |    X     |  Sand  |   1
       |    Y     |  Beach |   1
```

I also have the precursor dataframe to this, which looks like:

```
Group  |  Source  |  Name
___________________________
  A    |    X     |  Jolly
  A    |    X     |  Stone
  A    |    X     |  Jolly
  A    |    Y     |  Sand
  B    |    X     |  Sand
  B    |    X     |  Beach
  B    |    Y     |  Stone
```

Each `Group` is guaranteed to have a `Source` `X` and a `Source` `Y`, where the corresponding `Name`s for `X` and `Y` within a `Group` do not overlap. That is to say if a `Name` is found for `Source` `X`, it won't be found for `Source` `Y` within that group.

For example, I want to count how many times `Stone` and `Sand` are seen together for different `Source`s within a `Group`. So, `Jolly` is seen twice along with `Stone` once for `Source` `Y` `Name` `Sand` within `Group`  `A`. If I see `Jolly` and `Sand` frequently together across `Group`s, where each is from a different `Source` this may mean they reference the same entity.

How do I accomplish this with pandas?

I don't have a particular expected output in mind, perhaps this:

```
                                Y
            Stone | Sand  |  Beach  |  Water
   Stone      NaN     1       NaN       NaN
X  Sand       1      NaN      NaN       NaN
   ...      ...      ...      ...       ...
```

EDIT #1:
I was able to arrive at this based on @mozway answer:

```
def get_source_grouped_combos(df):
    src_x = df[df['Source'] == 'X'].groupby('Name').count()
    src_y = df[df['Source'] == 'Y'].groupby('Name').count()
    return list(product(src_x.index.values, src_y.index.values))

((dfex.loc[dfex['Group'].map(
    dfex.groupby(['Group','Source'])['Name']
    .agg(set)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(lambda x: len(set.intersection(*x))==0))])
 .groupby(['Group'])[['Source','Name']]
 .apply(get_source_grouped_combos)
 .explode('Name')
 .agg(set)
 .value_counts()
)
```

Which outputs this:

```
{Sand, Stone}     2
{Jolly, Sand}     1
{Beach, Stone}    1
dtype: int64
```

Apply is pretty slow, however. Is there a faster way?

EDIT #2:
When applying this to my actual dataset (which has all the same dtypes per column) the last 2 lines of the above solution:

```
 .agg(set)
 .value_counts()
```

Throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

`.agg(set)` seems to be wrapping the entire Series in a set instead of each value. How can I fix it so it counts the occurence of each `set` of values?

EDIT #3:
Seems as though the appearance of NaN values caused this. I would be interested to know why it wraps the series in a `set` when NaN values are in the series instead of the individual elements.

Comment: can you provide the explicit expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The expected output is unclear, but do you want something like:

```
from itertools import combinations
counts = (df
 .groupby('Group')['Name']
 .agg(lambda x: set(combinations(set(x), 2)))
 .explode('Name')
 .value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
(Sand, Stone)     2
(Jolly, Sand)     1
(Jolly, Stone)    1
(Sand, Beach)     1
(Beach, Stone)    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Updated to show expected output. This output format would work as well, but this doesn't take into account the `Source` column. I only want frequency counts when the `Name`s aren't from the same `Source` within the group.  `(Jolly, Stone)    1 (Sand, Beach)     1` <-- these rows shouldn't be there.

Comment: Your answer led me to what I believe to be the correct method. Please update your answer to provide the correct output so I can give you the credit. If you could provide a more efficient method than what I have given above, or point out why it is incorrect, that would be great.